# Can NServiceBus share a queue with other bus?

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

I wonder if it is feasible and easy having NSeviceBus "participating" to a pub/sub with other bus.
Let say we are using RabbitMQ as transport, would be feasible for other bus/app "subscribe" and/or "publish" message compliant with the NServiceBus message format?

Comment: The answers could be more specific about whether you can communicate with other bus platforms or applications if you provide some specifics about the messages you want to transmit.  What format will you need to use within NServiceBus? It doesn't force any particular format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [in this sample](http://docs.particular.net/samples/rabbitmq/native-integration/) you can mix NServiceBus apps with others that use native approach for talking with RabbitMQ.

Furthermore NServiceBus exposes the capability to [modify incoming/outgoing message headers](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/header-manipulation) or [messages themselves](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/message-mutators) to adapt them from/to others systems

Comment: Thanks @melkio the suggested sample is a great start. Do you have any suggestion/sample about how a native client can subscribe to a NserviceBus publisher using rabbitMQ as transport?

Comment: The simplest solution is to configure RabbitMQ routing manually: you have to create a new queue on which your native client app picks messages. Then bind this queue to all exchanges that represent interesting messages. In this case RabbitMQ does the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Any number of publishers and subscribers from any number of programming languages can use the same exchanges, queues and routing keys (bindings).

The larger question is will the message have the information required for cross-language / different service bus needs? You'll have to ensure the message producers and consumers have everything in order, on your own.